# Creating dummy hardware to send data to ros node with specific ip address

Tags: sockets, ros

I have ros node which is continuously polling on some packets and it accepts them only from specific ip, now I want to send some packets so that node will receive it.

How do I create dummy h/w which will have that specific ip address and my ros node will capture data from that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can set an IP in your node then you don't need DUMMY H/W.

You can use your own local IP (`127.0.0.1` AKA *localhost*) and custom port (if your code accepts it).